# How to set variable inside django template with javascript and pass it to views.py?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, materialize

I want to add a dark mode option to my django website, when you press a button I want to set a variable `dark-mode` to `True` and when you press again it sets `dark-mode` to `False` using javascript, and at `views.py` it will set the template-name as `home-dark.html` or `home-light.html` according to the `dark-mode` variable, how can I achieve this?

In case you need to know, I use Materialize CSS

Thanks from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it in the url and have a condition in your `view`, for example:

```
# your button should href to domain.com/your_view/?mode={your variable}
# then in your view
if request.GET.get('mode') == 'dark':
    return render(request, 'home-dark.html')
return render(request, 'home-light.html')
```

But that will work for one page only, if you want to keep that for the whole session I suggest you add it in `request.session` and then you can access it in any view. For example:

```
# in the above view before returning:
request.session['browse_mode'] = 'dark'

# then in all your views
if request.session.get('browse_mode') == 'dark':
    return render(request, 'dark-mode.html')
return render(request, 'light-mode.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I’ll use this